# Почему std::vector.push_back(new struct()) работает медленнее чем std::vector.push_back(struct_item)

Tags: c++, указатели, память, vector

хочу хранить в векторе некоторые структуры,(много).
Интересует вопрос почему такой код работает быстрее

```
struct A{
    uint64_t a1;
    uint8_t a2[12];
};
    {
        std::vector<A> *stdArray = new std::vector<A>;
        A temp;

        stdArray->reserve(SIZE);

        for(int ind=0;ind<SIZE;++ind){
            temp.a1= ind;
            stdArray->push_back(temp);
        }
    }
```

Чем такой:

```
{
    std::vector<A*> *stdArray = new std::vector<A*>;

    stdArray->reserve(SIZE);

    for(int ind=0;ind<SIZE;++ind)
        stdArray->push_back(new A());
}
```

В первом случае вызывается конструктор копирования а во втором нет, почему первое быстрее?

И еще вопрос, пытаюсь выделить память под ~20000000 элементов QVector
крашит программу с ошибкой выделения памяти, 32х компилятор MinGW, при этом std vector работает но медленнее, не пытаюсь выделить памяти больше разрешенных на 32х битах, никто не сталкивался? Почему QVector не хочет хранить столько же данных как std vector?

Comment: *"почему первое быстрее"* Потому что `new` медленный? Кстати, а зачем создавать сам вектор через `new`?

Comment: Разве во втором случае память не также выделяется для нового элемента вектора? Чтобы вектор передать в функцию без копирования.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat,  new не медленный. Она просто медленнее чем выделение памяти в стеке. Вдруг кто  то вас неправильно поймет...

Comment: То есть во втором случае все храниться в стеке? Как понять где память выделяется? new и malloc в куче, а в стеке разве не локальные переменные?

Comment: @Игорь, Локальные не статические обьекты хранятся в стеке,  для хранения в куче, правильно,  new и malloc.  Ваш объявленный  A temp какраз локальный и хранится в стеке.

Comment: Но когда я передаю его в вектор создаётся копия, она тоже храниться на стеке? Почему?

Comment: @Игорь Копия хранится в куче, в области зарезервированной вектором. И для передачи в функцию без копирования можно использовать ссылки, а не выделять память вручную, чтобы потом забыть её освободить

Comment: new std::vector<A> - удивительный код.

Answer (score 1):

Менеджер памяти - не самая быстрая система, так что основные потери времени у вас на

```
new A()
```

Конкретнее - на выделении памяти, обновлении массы служебных структур менеджера памяти и т.п., что по времени выполняется дольше, чем простое копирование 20 байт...